# Происхождение слова «шляпа»

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

**шляпа**
1. Головной убор с полями.
2. *разг., пренебр.* Рассеянный человек.
3. *разг.* Неприятная ситуация, положение.
([Смотри](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B0) здесь значения этого слова)

Вопрос: откуда появились два вторых значения?
Стоит ли это обсуждать и возможно ли вообще выяснить происхождение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, значение *шляпа* - *рассеянный человек* появилось потому, что шляпы носили рассеянные интеллигенты, часто попадавшие в нелепые ситуации, становившиеся жертвами мошенников, воров (можно ещё вспомнить слово *прошляпил*).

Значение *шляпа -  неприятная ситуация, положение* того же, в общем-то, происхождения, что и *шляпа - рассеянный человек*. В неприятные ситуации чаще остальных людей попадали нелепые и рассеянные интеллигенты, носившие шляпы.

Comment: Интересное предположение. Спасибо.